# PayPal unexpected error

Tags: android, paypal

Am using `PayPal SDK`. Everything seems to be OK, but after I login successfully I get an error. Its difficult to figure out as there are no logs. Its just a message saying "unexpected error".
Any help is highly appreciated. Refer the code and screen shot below.

```
PayPalPayment newPayment = new PayPalPayment();
        newPayment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal("0.99"));
        newPayment.setCurrencyType("USD");
        newPayment.setRecipient("xxxxx@gmail.com");
        newPayment.setMerchantName("xxxxx");
        newPayment.setPaymentType(PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_PERSONAL);
        newPayment.setCustomID("8873482296");
        newPayment.setMemo("Hi! I'm making a memo for a simple payment.");

        Intent paypalIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(newPayment, MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
        this.startActivityForResult(paypalIntent, 1);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Many be you are using , invalid email , which is not registered as a valid paypal account .
So if you are testing in the sandbox account then you can use this account : tharrahunmein@gmail.com

```
newPayment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal(1));
newPayment.setCurrencyType("USD");
newPayment.setRecipient("tharrahunmein@gmail.com");
```